# What do Objectname holds in C++?

Tags: java, c++, object

Eventhough C++ and java are two different languages. They have a lot in common

**in Java**
The objects hold a reference i.e. :

```
class Cls
{
    //some fields 
    //some methods

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Cls obj = new Cls();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

**Output** It gives a output similar to this : `Cls@372f7a8d`

Similarly

**in C++**

```
class Cls
{
    //some var
    //some methods
}

int main()
{
    Cls obj;
    std::cout << obj;
}
```

**Error** it gives an error :
`no operator "<<" matches these operands`

In C++ everything comes down to
either variables (that hold an address,a value, or just a reference to another variable)
or some function (a userdefined func, a keyword , or an operator)
**PS : correct me if am wrong**

I know this might seem meaningless to print object name but ..

I just wanna know if objnames in java holds reference to that object , then what does objectnames in C++ holds (*is it an address? ,a value ? or something more complex?* ). If so.. is there any way i can print it in console.

thanks in advance .

Comment: "_...objectnames ..."_ in C++ are for the compiler and programmer - they don't exist at runtime. See also [C++ Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)

Comment: In Java every class is derived from `object`, and printing a reference to `object` prints its address. In C++ there is no `object`, no "objectnames", and no default printing. If you want to display the contents of `Cls` you have to write a stream inserter. Don't try to apply things you know about Java to C++.

Comment: C++ is a lot more low-level than Java, and you'll often find a lot of the conveniences of Java, like being able to dump out arbitrary objects in a debug form, simply do not exist.

Comment: You should note that what is happening when you print a Java object via `System.out.println` is that the objects `toString()` method is called to create that output. This defaults in the Object class to <Classname>@<hashcode> and the hashcode in turn defaults to a native jvm implementation using the memory address. But there is no "object name" that gets automatically printed via system.out.println. If you create a class and override the toString method to always return `"Cowabanga Homies!"` then printing any object of that class via System.out.print will always result in printing that String.

Comment: *it gives an error : no operator "<<" matches these operands* -- Do not try to understand C++ by noting what Java does.  You will be going down a rabbit-hole if you are attempting to learn C++ by observing what Java (or what any other language) does.  Maybe you should figure out *how* to fix the error you are seeing so that `<<` will work with `Cls`-- that would be worth much more than trying to figure out C++ in terms of Java.

Comment: The languages have far less in common than you think. Don't be fooled by the syntactic similarities.

Comment: In C++ you'll need to overload an operator at namespace scope for this to work (usually signature `std::ostream& operator<<(std:ostream&, Cls const&);` This doesn't impose any limitations on what to exactly write to the string though... This has a similar effect to overloading the `toString` function in java, but works on a fundamentally different level; in C++ no virtual function in your own object is involved by default... The compiler just sees that the first operand of `<<` is convertible to `std::ostream&` and the second operand to`Cls const&`,so overload resolution chooses that signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Eventhough C++ and java are two different languages. They have a lot in common"

While the two languages are syntactically similar, the way they work differ a lot. One compiles into native code while the other is a managed language that is compiled to bytecode and then is executed by a VM (that is free to recompile it to native code or whatever ofcourse...).
The reason you can get away with this in Java:

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

is because Java was designed this way. Every class in java inherits from `java.lang.Object` and that class has a `toString()` method with a default implementation which generates the string as follows:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Note however that this is not an "object name" the way you put it. According to the java documentation it is

> a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method

Also note that the default `hashCode` implementation is described as:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java™ programming language.)

Which means that if both the toString and the hashCode implementations are left unchanged then what you end up with does contain the class name and some derivation of the instance address but the latter is not an implementation requirement.

So in short, it is not a universal "object name" mechanism. And it is recommended for most subclasses to override this method. Now to summarize, in case of Java

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

Just calls `obj.toString()` and prints whatever string that was returned. No magic happens, every detail is described in the language's implementation.

In case of C++, the language specification does not have anything like Java's `java.lang.Object`. There is no ever-present base class that has the operator << overloaded with some default implementation, so you can't just use it...

A library developer may decide to implement or use a base class similar to Java's (which may have a default << operator) and may try to enforce that all other classes must inherit from that base class. But that is left entirely to the developer.

In C++ you may use something like:

```
std::cout << "Memory address: " << static_cast<void*>(myPointer) << std::endl;
```

To print your instance's memory address. It also works with `this` so you may create your own default toString implementation if that is what you are after.

The reason why the two languages differ radically is a bit more complex than to cover in detail in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the name of an object normally refers directly to the storage holding the value. If you want a reference or an address you create that explicitly:

```cpp
Cls c;            // c is the actual object
auto & rc = c;    // rc is a reference to c
auto * pc = &c;   // pc holds the address of c
```

None of that has much to do with how you print an object though. You normally do that by overloading the `<<` operator:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Cls {
    int x;
    int y;
public:

   Cls(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Cls const &c) { 
        return os << "(" << c.x << ", " << c.y << ")";
    }
};

int main() {
    Cls x(1, 3);
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Produces output like this:

```
(1, 3)
```

`operator<<` typically takes a reference to the object it's going to print. That's usually done to avoid making an unnecessary copy though, not because it's strictly necessary. Some types don't allow copying either, in which case passing by reference is necessary.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "_An identifier can't change which object is identifies_": That isn't correct either. Automatic storage duration variables refer to a different object each time control passes through their definition (roughly). The standard itself doesn't provide a good description of that relationship at the moment. And placement-new can change to which object a name refers as well.

Comment: @user17732522 I disagree with some of those cases, but I hadn't thought of placement new. In any case, I think the term "value" is misused here, and an identifier refers to an entity and not its value. Some identifiers don't even refer to an entity which can have a value, like the name of a function.

Comment: @user17732522 On second though, aren't you supposed to use the pointer resulting from the new expression instead of the original identifier?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If the new object is transparently-replaceable with the old one, then all pointers, references and names that referred to the old object will refer to the new one. Because that requires the types to be the same up to cv-qualifiers, there isn't much practical difference in just considering the two objects to be the same, even if that is formally incorrect.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The name _denotes_ an entity like the variable or function (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-5.sentence-3), but as an expression, if it denotes a variable, it is an lvalue whose result is the object corresponding to the variable at runtime (which can be a different when the scope is re-entered). Unfortunately the standard currently conflates variables as compile-time entities and objects that are "instantiated" from these entities at runtime into one as you can see in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#pre-6.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: It's perfectly permissible and reasonable for a pointer to hold the address of something allocated on the free store, or for it to hold the address of some static or local variable. The latter is more common when passed as a parameter, but that's mostly a practical matter of "why are you using a pointer" than any sort of requirement.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It isn't clear to me which comment you are responding to.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That was in response to: "On second though, aren't you supposed to use the pointer resulting from the new expression instead of the original identifier?" Yes, pointers can point to objects created with a new expression, but they can also perfectly well refer to objects allocated in other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

"<<" is a ostream operator that outputs data of a base-out type.Now that you define a class,you should overload << operator(maybe it's hard for a beginner).And indeed how you define <<,what you output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Cls
{
    //some var
    //some methods
    private:
        int a;
        float b;
    public:
        void f1();
        Cls():a(0), b(0.0) {};
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Cls &cls) {
            return os << cls.a << " " << cls.b << std::endl;
        };
};

int main()
{
    Cls obj;
    std::cout << obj;
}
```